# php date usage for today and yesterday

Tags: php, xml, api, date

I am a beginner for php. I am trying to integrate an XML API to my system. Calling code is

```
$XML = simplexml_load_file('http://my.mydomain.com/stats/report.xml?api_key=XXXXXXXX&start_date='.date('Y-m-d').'&end_date='.date('Y-m-d'));
```

What I need to do is;

- start_date = yesterday
- end_date = today

I could not find how to describe.

Comment: Does the first question in the **Related** list help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP strtotime() function helps in this:

You could use

```
$XML = simplexml_load_file('http://my.mydomain.com/stats/report.xml?api_key=XXXXXXXX&start_date='.date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday')).'&end_date='.date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday'));
```

Yes its that simple, date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday')) gives you yesterday's date !!

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )
```

$time = A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in [Date and Time Formats.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

$now  = This is an optional parameter for the timestamp which is used as a base for the calculation of relative dates.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) call like so:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today') );
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('1 day ago') );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$Start_Date=date('d.m.Y',strtotime("-1 days"));
$End_Date = date('d.m.y', strtotime('today') );
```